# What's wrong with my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am working on this script to show my calendar and the error console says that "calendar is not defined". I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

this is the code for the .js page as requested by John WHS

```
    function calendar()
{

 var calDate = new Date("July 6, 2015");
    document.write("<table id = 'calendar_table'>");
writeCalTitle(calDate); 
    writeDayNames();
writeCalDays(calDate);

    document.write("</table>");

}


    //function for the title of the calendar
    //the parameter is a date object
    function writeCalTitle(calendarDay)
    {

        // This is an array for the months
        var monthName = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August"
        ,"September","October","November","December"]

        var thisMonth = calendarDay.getMonth();
        var thisYear = caalendarDay.getFullYear();

        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<th id='calendar_head' colspan='7'>");
        document.write(monthName[month] + " " +year);

        document.write("</th>");
        document.write("</tr>");
    }

     function writeDayNames()
 {
    var dayName = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    document.write("<tr>");
    // This is a for loop
    for(var i = 0; i<dayName.length; i++)
        {
        document.write("<th id='calendar_weekdays'>" + dayName[i]+"</th>");
        }

    document.write("</tr>");
 }


function daysInMonth(calendarDay)
{
var dayCount = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
var thisYear = calendarDay.getFullYear();
var thisMonth = calendarDay.getMonth();
if (thisYear % 4 == 0) 
    {

    if ((thisYear % 100 != 0 || (thisYear % 400 ==0 ))
    {
    dayCount[1] = 29;
    }
}
return dayCount[thisMonth];
}



function writeCalDays(calendarDay)
    {
    // says the starting day of the month
    var day = new Date(calendarDay.getFullYear(), calendarDay.getMonth(), 1 );
    var weekDay = day.getDay();

    // writes blank cells before the starting day
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var i = 0; i < weekDay; i++)
        {
        document.write("<td></td>");
        }

    // writes cells for the days of the month
    var totalDays = dayIn Month(calendarDay);

    for (var i = 1; i<= totalDays; i++)
        {
        day.setDate(i);
        weekDay = day.getDay();
        }
    if (weekDay == 0) document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td class='calendar_dates'>" + i + "</td>");
    if (i == highlightDay) 
        {
        document.write("<td class='calendar_dates' id='calendar_today'>" + i + "</td>");
        }
        else
        {
        document.write("<td class='calendar_dates'>" + i + "</td>");
        }

    if (weekDay == 6) document.write("</tr>");


    }
```

Comment: Is your function definition within `<script>` tags?

Comment: Why isn't the top bit in a `script` element as well?

Comment: Are there `<script>` tags around that JavaScript code? Or is it in a separate file? If it's in a separate file, is there a `<script>` element referencing it?

Comment: yes. the code is in a separate .js page and is in script tags. I added <script>s to the separate page but it didn't make a difference

Comment: I think I may have figured it out... There isnt a tag to connect the javascript page to the other one. (working out of a tutorial...)   Never mind. Didn't do a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put:

```
function calendar(){
    var calDate = new Date("July 6, 2015");
    document.write("<table id = 'calendar_table'>");
    writeCalTitle(calDate); 
    writeDayNames();
    writeCalDays(calDate);
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

Inside the script.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations should also be considered as scripts. Therefore...

```
<figure id="events">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calendar()
    {

        var calDate = new Date("July 6, 2015");
        document.write("<table id = 'calendar_table'>");
        writeCalTitle(calDate); 
        writeDayNames();
        writeCalDays(calDate);

        document.write("</table>");

    }

    calendar();

</script>
</figure>
```

... should give better results.

Comment: Well first, you're opening a table, but not using rows, nor cells. Show us the code for `write*` functions and most importantly : check the source code of your page. Maybe the code **was** generated, even though something made the browser's interpretation fail ^^

Comment: See if the table was printed :) A `<table>` tag which inner content is incorrect might not print. You should add the code of the `write*` functions to your question (writeCalTitle, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You must have the code inside the `<script>` tag, or loaded via `<script src="...">`.

Comment: I'm finding that when using notepad++ and trying to put in <script>s inside the .js file, they do not turn out right. They seem to think they are separate functions or something..

Comment: Read better. I wrote either inside `<script>` or loaded externally via `<script src="...">`. Overall, you question is lacking information - is the citation from one file? Which type (.js, .html)? I see you fixed it from the original, where naked JS was mixed with HTML - it is not correct, of course. JS should be put in .js and loaded in HTML via `<script src="..."></script>`.